# Using an Android-Support-Fragment in Preference Headers

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

My app supports Android versions up to Android 2.2, that's why in general I'm using support `Fragments` (i.e. `SherlockFragments`).

My preferences are build to use headers when API > 11 and the traditional preferences when lower. Now I have implemented a (support) `Fragment` with a logic that cannot be replicated with preferences only. On older Android version it will be launched within a simple `SherlockFragmentActivity` but on newer versions it is supposed to be launched from a header.

This is the problem: Headers expect native fragments. That's why on newer versions the preferences crash. Is there a possibility to circumvent this limitation?

I'm thinking of the following possibilities:

- Wrap the support Fragment within a native Fragment. Can I do that? If yes, how?
- Capture the click event from the header and launch the fragment myself on newer versions. Can I add simple preferences besides headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

I created a native `Fragment` that wraps my SherlockFragment.

```
public class HelperFragment extends ListFragment {
    MyFragment cp;

    public HelperFragment() {
        cp = new MyFragment();
    }
}
```

The overwritten calls like `onCreateView()` need to be forwarded but some need special treatment. Instead of `getActivity()` in `MyFragment` I used the following construct:

```
private Activity activity;

@Override
public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    activity = null;
}

public void setActivity(final Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

The `HelperFragment` calls the setter when it gets attached and detached and if `MyFragment` gets attached the usual way it works as usual.

In my case the `HelperFragment` is also a `ListFragment` so calls to `getListView()` need to be redirected. I solved it by overwritting `getListView()` in `MyFragment`:

```
private ListView listView;
@Override
public ListView getListView() {
    if (listView != null) {
        return listView;
    } else {
        return super.getListView();
    }
}

public void setListView(final ListView listView) {
    this.listView = listView;
}
```

and called `setListView()` in `HelperFragment`'s `onActivityCreated()` method. Depending on usage there will be other methods that need special treatment but the concept should be clear.